# Edit View in asp.net mvc - controller error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing web service in asp.net mvc and still having the same error connected with the code below:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int C)
    {
        var customers = _ourCustomerRespository.GetCustomers();
        var std = customers.Where(s => s.CustomerID == C).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(std);
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Customer C)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and when i try use my service i have error message

> The current request for action 'Edit' on controller type
>   'DefaultController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32) on type
>   WebApplication2.Controllers.DefaultController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(WebApplication2.Models.Customer) on
>   type WebApplication2.Controllers.DefaultController

Can anybody help me with solving that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you decorated your controller action with the **wrong** `HttpPost` attribute. You need [`this one`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Customer C)
```

The one you have used (`System.Web.Http.HttpPost`) is designed for ASP.NET Web API actions and has strictly zero effect when placed on an ASP.NET MVC controller action. So the ASP.NET MVC framework cannot disambiguate between the 2 `Edit` actions because they are using the same verb and thus you are getting the error.

Remark: please make sure that you tag your question correctly to avoid any confusions. Currently you have used the `asp.net-web-api` whereas the controller action you have shown is clearly `asp.net-mvc`. Those are 2 completely different frameworks.